# XMPP - How to join an existing MUC room

Tags: ios, objective-c, xmpp, xmppframework

How do I join an existing MUC on my openfire server?

I have managed to join the server with my credentials and all.

But I cant seem to find any code samples for how to join a MUC?

Comment: You have to be invited to a MUC room.

Answer (score 0):

0045 http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html

JUst follow all the steps and you are able to do Multi user chat. HOpe it works for you :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
- (void)joinRoomWithRoomName:(NSString *)roomName nickName:(NSString *)nickName 
    {
        if(roomName && nickName)
        {
            _xmppRoomStorage = [XMPPRoomHybridStorage sharedInstance];
            XMPPJID *roomJid = [XMPPJID jidWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@@%@.%@",roomName,@"conference",self.hostName]];
            _xmppRoom = [[XMPPRoom alloc] initWithRoomStorage:_xmppRoomStorage jid:roomJid];
            [_xmppRoom addDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
            [_xmppRoom activate:_xmppStream];
            NSXMLElement *history = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"history"];
            [history addAttributeWithName:@"maxstanzas" stringValue:MAX_ROOM_HISTORY];
            [_xmppRoom joinRoomUsingNickname:nickName history:history];
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"room creation arguments missing");
        }
    }
```